# Problem with adding JCombobox in JTable in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have added a combobox in a JTable, the adding code as follows:

```
Vector<String> header = new Vector<String>();
Vector data = new Vector();
String[] h = new String[]{"Music", "Movie", "Sport"};
header.add("Code");
header.add("Name");
header.add("Salary");
 header.add("Hobby");
loadData(); // Add some data to the table
DefaultTableModel tblModel;
tblModel = (DefaultTableModel) this.tblEmp.getModel();
tblModel.setDataVector(data, header);

// Adding combobox to the last column
TableColumn hobbyColumn = tblEmp.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
hobbyColumn.setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor(h));
```

Things worked fine until I dynamically add a new row to the table using the code:

```
Vector v = new Vector();
v.add("E333");
v.add("Peter");
v.add(343);
v.add(""); // This last colum is the combobox so I put it as ""

data.add(v);
tblEmp.updateUI();
```

Data is added to the table but the combobox in the last column cannot be selected anymore. The combobox is still displayed when I click on the row but cannot select a value.
How can I handle this problem, please?

Comment: I'm guessing that we'll not be able to figure out your problem based on the code not shown, and you can't post all of your code. Best to create a small compilable and runnable program that we can test and modify and that demonstrates your problem, an [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: At the minimum, you have to show us the code of MyComboBoxEditor which is probably the root of the problem. Besides, you shouldn't directly add the new row to your `data` Vector, but rather use `tblModel.addRow()` which will automatically trigger a UI update. By the way, updateUI() is not for refreshing the table but changing its LAF, hence you should **NEVER** use it..

Comment: You've been given all the help we can give you based on your question. Until you post your SSCCE we won't be able to provide any additional help.

Answer (score 2):

Never use the updateUI() method. Read the API to see what this method actually does. It has nothing to do with changing the data in a model.

JTable already supports a combo box editor so there is no need to create a custom MyComboBoxEditor. Read the JTable API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Tables", for a working example of using a combo box as an editor.